# building oracle docker image on mac os x fails with "This system does not meet the minimum requirements for swap space."

Tags: oracle, docker

I am using Docker Community Edition Version 17.03.0-ce-mac2 (15654) on OS X.

I am using [these (official) oracle docker files](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/dockerfiles)

I am using oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip as my installation binary.

When I run

```
:dockerfiles $ pwd
.../oracle/docker-images/OracleDatabase/dockerfiles

:dockerfiles $ ./buildDockerImage.sh -v 11.2.0.2 -x
```

I get this error:

```
Archive:  oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip
   creating: Disk1/
   creating: Disk1/upgrade/
  inflating: Disk1/upgrade/gen_inst.sql
   creating: Disk1/response/
  inflating: Disk1/response/xe.rsp
  inflating: Disk1/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm

This system does not meet the minimum requirements for swap space.  Based on
the amount of physical memory available on the system, Oracle Database 11g
Express Edition requires 2048 MB of swap space. This system has 1023 MB
of swap space.  Configure more swap space on the system and retry the
installation.

error: %pre(oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
error: oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64: install failed
Removing intermediate container 86bb92ebf0e5
```

This worked last week.  I can't recall if I did anything different back then.

What do I need to do to fix?

Comment: Can you confirm the error is calculating the space correctly? `Oracle Database 11g
Express Edition requires 2048 MB of swap space. This system has 1023 MB
of swap space.  Configure more swap space on the system and retry the
installation.` If its correct, try to allocate more swap space and retry.

Comment: That is what I am trying to figure out how to do @FarhadFarahi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that the virtual machine underpinning docker on os x has swap set to 1G.  When I found "ramonpires" answer in [this](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-for-mac-configure-swap-space/20656/2), it made it clear to me that I needed to add swap to that underlying vm.  The instructions in that post got me most of the way there, but I had to add one final step to get it to work.  So, full solution:

```
screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty
username：root
password：[empty]
close session：Ctrl+a d

free -m
```

This tells you how much swap is available.  Check it is less than 2G.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.file count=2000000 bs=1024
chmod go= /var/swap.file
mkswap /var/swap.file
echo "/var/swap.file swap swap defaults 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
swapon -a
```

The last line was missing from the linked to solution.  Now run

```
free -m
```

To ensure you have more than 2G swap, and then re-run

```
:dockerfiles $ ./buildDockerImage.sh -v 11.2.0.2 -x
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it may be exactly what I'm searching for to fix this problem on my Mac.

However, when I try to enter the first command ("free -m") in the TTY console started with the 'screen' command, I get an horribly messed up screen such as:
-----
rem

6n
n
6




/ # 




e -m
    d 1 2    8
6ree -m             
 f h
    M   3 2
--- 

What am I missing? Is there some configuration parameter to apply to 'screen' command? Thank you

Comment: No idea mate, sorry.  Getting screen to work at all was at the limits of my knowledge :)  You'll have to ask a screen expert.